# WordPress Index Page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

As I attempted to convert an HTML page to WordPress which is supposed to display the most recent post in big and the other ones in small, but now the small ones are not clickable at all.
Also, I don't know how to avoid calling the latest one on the second function, therefore it is displayed twice (both in big and first small one as well).
Would anyone know how to correct these please?
Thank you all in advance for your time and attention.

Index:

```
<section id="blog_section">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="columns">
        <h1 class="main-title turquoise">sharing is caring</h1>
        <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="columns large-10 large-offset-1 medium-10 medium-offset-1">

                    <div class="main posts">
                        <?php query_posts('posts_per_page=1');
                        if(have_posts()) :
                    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                            $latest_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args); ?>
                                <div>
                                    <?php get_template_part('template-parts/content', get_post_format()); ?>
                                </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php else : ?>
                    <?php get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'none'); ?>
                <?php endif;  wp_reset_query(); ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <?php if(have_posts()) :
                    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                                <div class="columns large-4 medium-6">
                                    <div class="posts small-post">
                                <?php get_template_part('template-parts/content', get_post_format()); ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                    <?php endwhile; ?>

                            <?php the_posts_pagination(
                array(
                    'prev_text' => __('<i class="posts-nav fa fa-angle-left"></i>', 'textdomain'),
                    'next_text' => __('<i class="posts-nav fa fa-angle-right"></i>', 'textdomain'),
              )); ?>

                <?php else : ?>
                    <?php get_template_part('template-parts/content', 'none'); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Content-part:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

        <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) : ?>
                    <div class="post-info">
                        <?php the_title( '<h2>', '</h2>' ); ?>
                        <span><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <?php the_time(); ?> &nbsp; <i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> <?php the_date(); ?></span>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </a>
      <?php } ?>

</article>
```

Comment: you use `'posts_per_page=1'` and `wp_reset_query();`, so actually you are supposed to get just 1 article on your page, and because you reset the query, it starts from beginning when you try to display the rest, and displays it again in small. Can you confirm that you get only 1 article, both in big and small? If you wan to have 1 big and 4 small for example, try with `'posts_per_page=5'` (total number), and move the `wp_reset_query();` after the very last `endif` in index

Comment: Dear Kaddath, thank you very much first of all for taking the time to respond and help me out.
With regards to the final posts, they appear as they should (one main one and 6 smaller ones below), however only the main one is clickable and all the others aren't.

Comment: ah yes forgot this detail: when you do `query_posts`, you alter the main query (which automatically gets articles depending on global settings). When you `wp_reset_query`, it goes back to this main request, that's why your first article is there twice. Also this: `$latest_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);` is never used. Is is not really recommended to alter the main query with `query_posts` and let the main query do the job, or use only `wp_get_recent_posts`, but it is a different syntax, you would foreach on `$latest_posts` and get values from it

Comment: try maybe to simply delete these: `query_posts('posts_per_page=1');` and `wp_reset_query();`. You have also to remove the first while loop, to display just one article first. (the second loop will normally start from article 2 automatically). So it would be `if(have_posts()) : the_post();`, with removing the first `<?php endwhile; ?>`

Comment: Dear Kaddath, thank you very much for your help, that fixed it perfectly for the first article, however I'm still unable to click and select any of the smaller ones (only the first one appears to be selectable). Any idea of what may be causing this?

Comment: Fixed it, seems like all it needed was a bit of z-index correction.
Thank you so much once again for all your help Kaddath, and if you'd like to post your answer as a comment, I'd be happy to upvote and confirm it as solving this issue.